# Create Multiple Dataframe based on first string value

Tags: python, pandas

**Hello World,**

Below Is the DF

```
Code  Name 
15    Amiks
12    Poiu
11    Zeps
157   Alis
112   Pars
```

Not an expert in Python, I'd like to create multiple df based on first string of column 'Name'.
The desired output will be :

df_a

```
Code  Name 
15    Amiks
157   Alis
```

df_p

```
Code  Name 
12    Poiu
112   Pars
```

What I have done for one letter:

```
df_A = df[df['Name'].str.startswith('A')]
df_A
```

Question:
How can I iterate over all 'First Letter' and create multiple DF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create dictionary of DataFrames by convert `groupby` object by first letter created by indexing, `str[0]`:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['Name'].str[0])))

print (dfs['A'])
   Code   Name
0    15  Amiks
3   157   Alis

print (dfs['P'])
   Code  Name
1    12  Poiu
4   112  Pars
```

If want test all keys:

```
print (list(dfs.keys()))
['A', 'P', 'Z']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary and name the keys according to the first letter:

```
import string
dfs = {}
for i in list(string.ascii_uppercase):
    dfs[i] = df[df['Name'].str.startswith(i))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the **asterisk** operator for un-packing:

```
dfs = dict([*df.groupby(df['Name'].str[0])])
```

```
print(dfs['A'], '\n')
print(dfs['P'])

   Code   Name
0    15  Amiks
3   157   Alis 

   Code  Name
1    12  Poiu
4   112  Pars
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you!